# How to correctly use 'percentParent' in sunburst graphs with only 1 central node?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, sunburst-diagram

So I'm trying to build a Plotly sunburst graph that displays `percentParent` for each element in the graph. This works fine for all elements except for when I have only a single option for the central node/ring/whatever (see example below)

[image]

Since the central node obviously does not have a parent, it appears to bug out and display the bracketed call on `percentParent` from the `texttemplate` field. However, if there are 2 (or more) central nodes, it automatically calculates each's percentage of the sum total of the two.

My question is:
When I have only 1 central node, how can I either hide this field for the central node only or make it correctly display "100%"?

Example code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'node_names': ['Center', 'Yes', 'No'],
                   'node_parent': ['', 'Center', 'Center'],
                   'node_labels': ['Center', 'Center_Yes', 'Center_No'],
                   'node_counts': [1000, 701, 299]})


fig = go.Figure(
       data=go.Sunburst(
        ids=df["node_names"],
        labels=df["node_labels"], 
        parents=df["node_parent"],
        values=df["node_counts"],
        branchvalues="total",
        texttemplate = ('%{label}<br>%{percentParent:.1%}'),
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rpanai : updated post with mcve code

Comment: I saw your question on community.plotly too. It seems to me that here there is a possible bug or they should add a conditional template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I found a possible way reading the help `go.Sunburst.texttemplate?`

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'node_names': ['Center', 'Yes', 'No'],
                   'node_parent': ['', 'Center', 'Center'],
                   'node_labels': ['Center', 'Center_Yes', 'Center_No'],
                   'node_counts': [1000, 701, 299]})

fig=go.Figure(
    data=go.Sunburst(
        ids=df["node_names"],
        labels=df["node_labels"], 
        parents=df["node_parent"],
        values=df["node_counts"],
        branchvalues="total",
        texttemplate = ('%{label}',
                        '%{label}<br>%{percentParent:.1%}',
                        '%{label}<br>%{percentParent:.1%}',
                        '%{label}<br>%{percentParent:.1%}'),
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

You could eventually modify the firs element in `texttemplate` as `'%{label}<br>100%'`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think to pass an array to `texttemplate`. Thanks!